# jenkins parametized build value not saving?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins build that I'm trying to add parameterized values for.

I click: This project is parameterized
I add a boolean value. But now I don't see the option to save that value to my build. What am I missing?

Comment: You added the [tag:jenkins-pipeline], so you're talking about a pipeline job? This would overwrite manual changes, if you call `properties` in your pipeline. Further, when they're defined using pipeline, they have to run once and only affect the subsequent build.

Comment: Being a bit more explicit, showing your pipeline code (or screen shot, if you don't use Jenkins Pipelines), would help us.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being more specific, but I solved my problem. If you add the the following in Jenkinsfile it will display a 'Build With Parameters' link in the UI:

```
parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'Deploy', defaultValue: false, description: 'Deploy Versioned Artifact')
}
```